# Sort Table Rows That Have Been Added From Localstorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage, tablesorter

I'm using localstorage for a project, and am trying to sort a table using the tablesorter2 jquery plugin. I keep getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined

I have a function running on a submit button click that adds these rows from localstorage that my friendly javascript console believes do not exist.

Is there a way to call rows that have been added from localstorage rather than those in the original markup?

Here's the code for adding the table rows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.extend($.fn, {
        storeitem: function() {

            //add a new id for each array
            $newTeam = $('#team');

            //set up unique ids for each array
            var i = Number(localStorage.getItem('team-counter')) + 1;

            // create condition to add or loop through new entry
            if ($newTeam.val() !== "") {
                // Take the value of the input field and save it to localStorage
                localStorage.setItem("team-" + i, $newTeam.val());

                // Set the to-do max counter so on page refresh it keeps going up instead of reset
                localStorage.setItem('team-counter', i);
            }

            //use serializeArray to simplify array creation
            //  var teaminfo = $("#newTeamForm").serializeArray();

            var teaminfo = {};
            var givemethat = $.each($('#newTeamForm').serializeArray(), function() {
                teaminfo[this.name] = this.value;
            });
            //alert(teaminfo.teamname);
            //$('div.second').replaceWith('<h2>New heading</h2>');
            $("#standings tr:last-child").after('<tbody><tr><td>' + teaminfo.teamname + '</td> <td></td><td></td> <td></td></tr></tbody>' );
            $("#standings").tablesorter();
            //$("#standings > tbody:last").after("<tr>" +  + "</tr>");
            //store data in key value pair and stringify
            localStorage.setItem("team-" + i, JSON.stringify(teaminfo));

            //  var neat = localStorage.setItem('teamname')

            var teamName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("team-" + i));

        }//storeitem

    });//extend

});//doc ready
```

To run the sort function, I ran:

```
$('#standings').tablesorter();
```

The function worked when I added table rows manually to my markup, but when they were added from localstorage using the function above.

Please let me know if this makes sense. I'm a new developer so please excuse the vagueness.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to insert into the localstorage, and show us the code you're using that's producing the error. These are key pieces of the puzzle and will likely lead to a larger pool of individuals being interested in addressing your issue.

Comment: Why has this question been modded down without a given reason? It is programming related and determinate, if a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem I see is that the code is adding a new `tbody` for every row it adds:

```
$("#standings tr:last-child").after('<tbody><tr><td>' + teaminfo.teamname + '</td> <td></td><td></td> <td></td></tr></tbody>' );
```

this should look something like this:

```
$("#standings tr:last-child").after('<tr><td>' + teaminfo.teamname + '</td> <td></td><td></td> <td></td></tr>' );
```

Although, I don't see how you're looping through and adding new the data to the empty table cells.

The part that is missing is that once you've added all the rows, you'll need to update tablesorter - see [this demo](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-empty-table.html).

```
$("table").trigger("update");
```